# css @media not working as expected

Tags: css

This is the first time I'm using the @media. Simply put all I want to do is apply the following style ONLY when the screen size gets substantially smaller. Here are the styles:

```
td { border: 0.5px solid  #0071bc; }
tr{padding-bottom: 0.5em;}
tr td:first-child { border-top-left-radius: 0.5em; border-top-right-radius: 0.5em; border-top-width: 0.2em; }
tr td { border-left-width: 0.2em; border-right-width: 0.2em; }
tr td:last-child { border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5em;  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5em; border-bottom-width: 0.2em; padding-bottom: 0.8em;}
```

I'm currently using the following code:

```
@media only screen and ( min-width: 15em ) {
td { border: 0.5px solid  #0071bc; }
tr{padding-bottom: 0.5em;}
tr td:first-child { border-top-left-radius: 0.5em; border-top-right-radius: 0.5em; border-top-width: 0.2em; }
tr td { border-left-width: 0.2em; border-right-width: 0.2em; }
tr td:last-child { border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5em;  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5em; border-bottom-width: 0.2em; padding-bottom: 0.8em;}
}
```

Some how the following code styles the table in full screen and small screen code. I just want it to apply the styles when the screen size gets smaller than 15em

Comment: u should use max-width..  `@media only screen and ( max-width: 15em )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use max-width..

```
@media only screen and ( max-width: 15em )
```

Answer (score 1):

use max-width if you want to apply style to a browser that has at most the width of 15em :)